# grep not performing very well on large files, is there an alternative?

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a diff that essentially equates to either additional unique lines or to lines that have moved around in the file, and thus their line numbers have changed.  To identify what is truly a new addition, I run this little perl snippet to separate the 'resolved' lines from the 'unresolved' lines:

```
perl -n -e'
    /^\-([^\-].*?)\([^,\(]+,\d+,\d+\).*$/ && do { print STDOUT "$1\n"; next; };
    /^\+([^\+].*?)\([^,\(]+,\d+,\d+\).*$/ && do { print STDERR "$1\n"; next; };
' "$delta" 1>resolved 2>unresolved
```

This is quite quick in fact and does the job, separating a 6000+ line diff into two 3000+ line files, removing any references to line numbers and unified diff decoration.  Next comes the grep command that seems to run at 100% CPU for nearly 9 minutes (real):

```
grep -v -f resolved unresolved
```

This is essentially removing all resolved lines from the unresolved file.  The output, after 9 minutes, is coincidentally 9 lines of output - the unique additions or unresolved lines.

Firstly, when I have used grep in the past, it's been pretty good at this, so why in this case is it being exceptionally slow and CPU hungry?

Secondly, is there a more efficient alternative way of removing lines from one file that are contained within another?

Comment: Okay, I think I answered my own question a bit with the figures.  Grep is parsing 3000 lines of a file, potentially 3000 times, so perhaps equivalent to parsing a 9,000,000 line file.  But that's still not that huge.  It's almost as if grep is taking 60 seconds to parse 1,000,000 lines.

Comment: Note that `.*$` is useless

Comment: Sure, but I just figured ^ might get a bit lonely without a $. :-)

Comment: I think there would be benefits from building a single regexp using Regexp::Assemble instead of having a slew of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grep is probably parsing that file entirely for each and every match it's been told to find.  You can try "fgrep" if it exists on your system, or grep -F if it doesn't, which forces grep to use the Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), which attempts to match all strings simultaneously, only necessitating one run-through of the file.

Comment: Wow, what a difference.  Here is the timing for the fgrep solution: real 0m0.049s, user 0m0.041s, sys 0m0.009s

Comment: Found this useful 8 years later after multiple failed grep attempts of my own and after going through many other unhelpful questions/answers. Went from at best "grep: memory exhausted" (I didn't know grep could do that) to finishing with all correct matches in <30 seconds. ~328k search strings ~8M lines.

Answer (score 9):

If the lines to be matched across the two files are supposed to be exact matches, you can use sort and uniq to do the job:

```
cat resolved resolved unresolved | sort | uniq -u
```

The only non-duplicated lines in the pipeline above will be lines in *unresolved* that are not in *resolved*. Note that it's important to specify *resolved* twice in the cat command: otherwise the uniq will also pick out lines unique to that file. This assumes that *resolved* and *unresolved* didn't have duplicated lines to begin with. But that's pretty easy to deal with: just sort and uniq them first

```
sort resolved | uniq > resolved.uniq
sort unresolved | uniq > unresolved.uniq
```

Also, I've found fgrep to be significantly faster if I'm trying to match fixed strings, so that might be an alternative.

Comment: The `cat resolved resolved unresolved` solution worked and within 1 second.  I'll also give the fgrep solution a shot.

Comment: nice! A variant of this problem is something I occasionally ask in interviews. Always interesting to see the things people come up with.

Comment: The fgrep solution seems slightly faster, but marginally.  Here's the timing for this solution: real 0m0.220s, user 0m0.212s, sys 0m0.004s

Comment: You can eliminate two processes by doing: `sort -u resolved resolved unresolved`.  Nice solution!

Comment: `sort -u` is not the same as `sort | uniq -u` because of the `-u` that show ONLY uniq lines an not a uniq occurance of each lines

Comment: @JRFerguson, to elaborate on @NeronLeVelu's point: `sort -u` is equivalent to `sort | uniq` , i.e. it'll print each line only once, regardless of duplicates. So even the duplicated lines from `resolved` will be printed, albeit only once. `uniq -u` is different; it'll print a line only if it has no duplicates. So it'll catch the unique lines from `unresolved`

Comment: @RS239 Point noted. I had mis-interpreted the OP's question and hastily sought to factor out potentially extraneous processes.